# Mysql Groupby and Orderby problem

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Here is my data structure

[alt text http://luvboy.co.cc/images/db.JPG](http://luvboy.co.cc/images/db.JPG)

when i try this sql

```
select rec_id, customer_id, dc_number, balance
from payments
where customer_id='IHS050018'
group by dc_number
order by rec_id desc;
```

something is wrong somewhere, idk

I need

```
rec_id  customer_id   dc_number   balance

2        IHS050018      DC3        -1
3        IHS050018      52         600
```

I want the recent balance of the customer with respective to dc_number ?

Thanx

Comment: what do you think should happen? Are you looking for the overall balance?

Comment: I want the recent balance of the customer with respective to dc_number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to get this

```
select p.rec_id, p.customer_id, p.dc_number, p.balance
from payments p
where p.rec_id IN (
    select s.rec_id
    from payments s
    where s.customer_id='IHS050018' and s.dc_number = p.dc_number
    order by s.rec_id desc
    limit 1);
```

Also if you want to get the last balance for each customer you might do

```
select p.rec_id, p.customer_id, p.dc_number, p.balance
from payments p
where p.rec_id IN (
    select s.rec_id
    from payments s
    where s.customer_id=p.customer_id and s.dc_number = p.dc_number
    order by s.rec_id desc
    limit 1);
```

What I consider essentially another way is utilizing the fact that select rec_id with order by desc and limit 1 is equivalent to select max(rec_id) with appropriate group by, in full:

```
select p.rec_id, p.customer_id, p.dc_number, p.balance
from payments p
where p.rec_id IN (
    select max(s.rec_id)
    from payments s
    group by s.customer_id, s.dc_number
    );
```

This should be faster (if you want the last balance for every customer), since max is normally less expensive then sort (with indexes it might be the same).

Also when written like this the subquery is not correlated (it need not be run for every row of the outer query) which means it will be run only once and the whole query can be rewritten as a join.

Also notice that it might be beneficial to write it as correlated query (by adding where s.customer_id = p.customer_id and s.dc_number = p.dc_number in inner query) depending on the selectivity of the outer query.

This might improve performance, if you look for the last balance of only one or few rows.

Comment: You're simply superb, thanx for saving much of my time
thanQ

Comment: I made an edit just now because I missed the condition that you want last balance in respect to dc_number (previous version was giving the last balance per customer regardless)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to do this in SQL without having window functions (like [those in Postgres 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)). You probably have to iterate over the dataset in your code and get the recent balances that way.

Answer (score -1):

ORDER comes before GROUP:

```
select rec_id, customer_id, dc_number, balance
from payments
where customer_id='IHS050018'
order by rec_id desc
group by dc_number
```

Comment: nor does it come before, nor does it matter :) if you have group by then the columns not listed under group by blance, rec_id, customer_id will be selected in an arbitrary fashion (SQL standard actually prescribes that any column in select should either be in group by or have an aggregate function applied to it; mysql extends the standard, but it is not terribly useful, more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)